# ¿Como seleccionar una rango entre fechas para evitar un insert SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada `etapa` la cual tiene `id_etapa, etapa_inicial, etapa_final`... ¿que sentencia (sql) puedo realizar para mostrar las etapas que se encuentren entre la `etapa_inicial` y la `etapa_final`?.

 ya que la idea es que si se creo la siguiente etapa:..

**EJ:**

```
etapa_inicial: 28/03/2017
etapa_final: 30/04/2017
```

cuando vuelva a realizar un `insert` no se inserten `etapas` que estén dentro de ese rango existente...

Espero haberme hecho entender y agradecería la colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM etapa
WHERE (etapa_inicial >= '28/03/2017' AND etapa_inicial <= '30/04/17')
OR (etapa_final >= '28/03/2017' AND etapa_final <= '30/04/17');
```

Si lo que quieres saber es solo si insertar puedes cambiar el * por un `COUNT(*)` y en tu programa si es más de uno el resultado del query no insertarlo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la opción `BETWEEN`.

Ejemplo:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM etapa where fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_1' AND '$fecha_2' ORDER BY id_etapa DESC";
```

... y de ahí sacar los `id_aporte` dentro de este rango para especificar en otro filtro:

```
select * FROM etapa where id_etapa !="$id_etapa".
```